# Disable "Send as XPS Attachment" Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, group-policy, xps-viewer

Is there a way to disable this option either via Group Policy or via some form of registry hack?

Normally I would go down the route of telling users not to send as XPS and send as something else but with our recent upgrade to 2007 lots of users are banding these files around.  Unfortunately our version of Citrix does not play nicely with XPS documents and we end up having to log them out.  Am told the fix for Citrix is not forthcoming so wondered if I could bury my head in the sand and disable the option all together.

Regards

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

1. You need [2007 Office system (SP2) Administrative Template files](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=73d955c0-da87-4bc2-bbf6-260e700519a8&displaylang=en)
2. open Group Policy Object Editor and browse to: `User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Microsoft Office 2007 System/Microsoft Save As PDF and XPS add-ins`
3. Select `Disable Microsoft Save As PDF and XPS add-ins`
4. Enable it and select `Disable XPS`

That's it. Users won't see `send as XPS` option anymore. This will also disable the Save as XPS option but in your case it's probably acceptable.

[image: group policy editor]

Comment: thanks for this that is exactly what i was searching for!